# Extract Strings Using AWS Athena or PrestoDB Regex Function

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-athena, presto, text-extraction

I have a table named

> logs

and column named

> url

whose value is like this

```
https://api.abc.com:443/xyz/live/dashboard_critical/v1?cust_id=-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111%7C-1111&model_id=&startdate=2021-06-29&enddate=2021-07-28&wcombo=&site_id=&instance=&unit=&combo=&source=&priority=&verification=&critical=Yes%7Ctrue&percentile=95&startevent=receiveddatetime&endevent=uploadtohostdatetime
```

I trying to extract all strings after **'/'** OR **'?'** OR **'%7C'** OR **'&'**

I am able to extract it individually but not all 4 together

```
SELECT regexp_extract_all(url, '\d+[/]*')
FROM logs.url
WHERE request_verb='GET'
        AND REGEXP_LIKE(url, 'https://api.abc.com:443/xyz/live/');
```

I am looking for output like below

```
[https:,api.abc.com:443,xyz,live,dashboard_critical,v1,cust_id=-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,-1111,model_id=,startdate=2021-06-29,enddate=2021-07-28,wcombo=,site_id=,instance=,unit=,combo=,source=,priority=,verification=,critical=Yes,true,percentile=95,startevent=receiveddatetime,endevent=uploadtohostdatetime]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_split(str, regexp)` function, as a regexp pattern concatenate all values by wich string should be splitted using `|` (OR in regexp), it will produce array required. Note: some characters have special meaning in Presto CLI or regexp and need shielding.

```
select regexp_split(url,'/+|\?|%%7C|&')
```

Regexp meaning:

`/+` - one or more slash

`|` - OR

`\?`  - literally `?`, needs shielding by backslash because `?` has special meaning in regexp

`|` - OR

`%%7C` - literally `%7C`. `%` has special meaning in Presto CLI and presto is using double-character notation for shielding.

`|` - OR

`&` - literally `&`

After you got an ARRAY, you can concatenate it or explode, etc

Comment: @user3198755 Edited: `%` has special meaning only in Presto, not in regexp